# Localization at annihilators of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

I was reading this [post](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01PL) and on line  +10-11 of the proof of lemma 27.25.1, it seems to claim the following:

> Let $A$ be a ring, $I \subseteq A$ an ideal, and $M$ an $A$-module. Let $M_I:=\{ x \in M\,: \, Ix=0 \}$.
> Let $D(f)$ be a basic open set contained in $\operatorname{Spec}(A) \setminus V(I)$. Then
> $$ (M_I)_{f} = M_{f},$$
> where the subscript denotes localization.

Is this true? If so, how does  one show this?

Answer (score 1):

In the case where $A$ is an integral domain and $0\neq I\subseteq A$, then taking $M$ to be some free module over $A$ we would have $M_I=0$ and so $(M_I)_f=0\neq M_f$.